# Unable to install Don stewart's Haskell plugins library on Windows 8 using stack 1.1.2 with ghc-7.10.3

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When I attempt to install plugins I get the following error:

```
>stack haddock plugins    
    [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Temp\stack
3768\plugins-1.5.5.0\Setup.lhs, C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Temp\stack3768\plugi
ns-1.5.5.0\.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\setup\Main.o )
    Linking C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Temp\stack3768\plugins-1.5.5.0\.stack-wo
rk\dist\2672c1f3\setup\setup.exe ...
    Configuring plugins-1.5.5.0...
    configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
    checking build system type... ./config.guess: unable to guess system type

    This script, last modified 2002-07-23, has failed to recognize
    the operating system you are using. It is advised that you
    download the most up to date version of the config scripts from

        ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/config/

    If the version you run (./config.guess) is already up to date, please
    send the following data and any information you think might be
    pertinent to <config-patches@gnu.org> in order to provide the needed
    information to handle your system.
```

Now this error seems to be linux/unix specific but I am running on Windows so I am not sure what to do. Can anyone advise on what to do?

Comment: `autoconf` is fully available and has worked on Windows, for a very long time (the fact that the script tells you that it ran and produced an error is proof that your machine can indeed run the script). This is just a bug in the script (if you can call it that - detecting the OS in such a way is and always has been a horrible hack). What provides `autoconf` on your system (cygwin, msys, native build, possibly even the *nix subsystem (is that available on W8? I don't actually know))?

Comment: The portability table at https://github.com/stepcut/plugins#readme (last update 11 years ago) doesn't even list Windows. I wouldn't set my hopes too high to get this working on Windows then…